# Python Interpreter in Jython

Tags: java, python, jython

All I'm trying to do is pass an argument to the python interpreter so it can be passed as an argument for a module.

**E.g. I have the following defined in a py file:**

```
    def print_twice(test):
       print test
       print test
```

**I want to pass it the argument "Adam", so I've tried:**

```
    // Create an instance of the PythonInterpreter
    PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter();

    // The exec() method executes strings of code
    interp.exec("import sys");
    interp.exec("print sys");

    PyCode pyTest = interp.compile("Adam", "C:/Users/Adam/workspace/JythonTest/printTwice.py");
    System.out.println(pyTest.toString());
```

**I've also tried:**

```
        interp.eval("print_twice('Adam')");
```

I've been using the following Jython API but I don't understand it well:
http://www.jython.org/javadoc/org/python/util/PythonInterpreter.html#compile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

I would be very grateful for your advices.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
interp.exec("import YOUR_PYTHON_FILE.py");
interp.exec("YOUR_PYTHON_FILE.print_twice('Adam')");
```

Its equivalent in a python console is this:

```
>>> import YOUR_PYTHON_FILE.py
>>> YOUR_PYTHON_FILE.print_twice('Adam')
Adam
Adam
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I got the following error in the console:

        Exception in thread "main" Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
        ImportError: No module named printTwice.

Comment: printTwice.py is saved in the same project. I've also tried moving it to the source folder. I'm going wrong somehwere, but not sure where...

Comment: When executing in the console printTwice.py has to be in the working directory (where you are when you execute the console) if you follow my code.

The path using Jython should be specified in the Jython Documentation:

http://www.jython.org/

Comment: I'm not sure how to save the py file to the same working directory, so I will try to find out how to do this.

Comment: Just copy it in the directory you're executing the Python console

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new to this.... how do I find which directory it is? I'm using Eclipse.... I'm looking at the PyDev settings etc but haven't found it yet...

Comment: This should be the path to your file : `os.path.abspath(__file__)/printTwice.py` so you can do `import os.path.abspath(__file__)/printTwice.py`

Comment: Thanks for your help Andreu.... I haven't got it working yet, but is this correct? interp.exec("import os.path.abspath(C:/Users/Adam/workspace/CodeWars/printTwice.py)");
   interp.exec("printTwice.print_twice('Adam')"); Really sorry

Comment: Try: `interp.exec("import os.path.abspath(__file__)/printTwice.py)"); interp.exec("printTwice.print_twice('Adam')"); `

__file__ is an intern variable that tells Python that you're accessing to these file. Tell me if it works to update the solution for future people with the same question :)

Comment: This returned the following error: Exception in thread "main" SyntaxError: ("mismatched input '(' expecting NEWLINE", ('<string>', 1, 22, 'import os.path.abspath(__file__)/printTwice.py)\n'))

Comment: Open another question with this doubt, it'll be so long and confusing here.

Comment: Thanks Andreu..... I've opened a new one here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31756461/python-interpreter-jython-execution-of-modules.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84897/discussion-between-andreu-rodriguez-i-donaire-and-user3742439).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to explicitly compile the script, just import it and the interpreter will take care of compilation. Something like this (assuming `printTwice.py` is in the working directory of your program:

```java
interp.exec("from printTwice import print_twice");
interp.exec("print_twice('Adam')");
```

You don't need to use `interp.eval` on the second line assuming that `print_twice` does actually contain `print` statements; if it just returns a string then you probably want
`System.out.println(interp.eval("print_twice('Adam')"));`.