# Python Interpreter Jython - execution of modules

Tags: java, python, jython

Here's the link to the problem:
[Python Interpreter in Jython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31752559/python-interpreter-in-jython)

**The following was a potential solution:**

```
    interp.exec("import os.path.abspath(__file__)/printTwice.py)");
    interp.exec("printTwice.print_twice('Adam')");
```

**However it returned an error:**

This returned the following error: Exception in thread "main" SyntaxError: ("mismatched input '(' expecting NEWLINE", ('', 1, 22, 'import os.path.abspath(file)/printTwice.py)\n'))

Comment: `import os.path.abspath(__file__)/printTwice.py)` does not make sense. If `printTwice.py` is the module that you are trying to import, then the import statement should be `import printTwice`.

Comment: Thanks for helping mzjn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
interp.exec("import printTwice");
interp.exec("printTwice.print_twice('Adam')");
```

This should work.

Comment: Thanks Andreu. I will try this once I figure out how to copy the file into same working directory as Python console. I will let you know if it works

Comment: Marvellous, it worked. Thanks Andreu and everyone else that contributed.